# Snowflake random distribution

Tags: javascript, noise

I am making a simple animation for fun with a bit of a festive theme. The component I am working on right now is some snowflakes falling. I am keeping things simple; several layers of snowfall each on a separate canvas which move downwards at some rate, each canvas wraps back to the top to make a never-ending fall of snow with parallax.

Currently the position of each snowflake is random (using Math.random()), but the effect is a bit lack lustre, far too even. What I want is snow function that produces a better looking distribution.

The pseudo-code for positioning the flakes looks something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var coords = placeFlake();
  // Take the generated co-ords and place a snowflake on the canvas.
}
function placeFlake() {
  // Just return an array of random co-ords within width and height.
  var x = // random number within the width
  var y = // random number within the height
  return [x,y];
}
```

Just wondered if anybody had any ideas for a replacement for placeFlake()?

Comment: Take a look at [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: I think the key to making this look natural/appealing is going to be to implement parallax in the falling snow. This will add the illusion of depth.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax

Comment: What you could do is make your snowflakes jiggle slightly from side to side and sometimes accelerate downwards for a step or two. It's all about giving the illusion of realism ;) What a merry question though, thanks!

Comment: A degree of jiggling is something I have in mind, but for now I'm just going to have static snowflakes. I currently have several layers of parallax to make a deeper effect. But really it's the distribution that's letting it down, having it purely random is too even.

Comment: I agree with others, although I don't see your random method at all. x,y seem undefined, not random. However, varying the SIZE, adding parallax, and moving some planes slightly left or right as well as down will create a better illusion.

Comment: Sorry, the random method I had in place was supposed to be a placeholder or pseudo-code, I have edited the question to make it more clear.